# Can creatures with summoning sickness block?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are you able to block with a creature that has summoning sickness? My friend always has at least 1 [Moaning Wall](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoaning%20Wall%5d) in his hand and plays it each chance he gets, even when I attack and it has summoning sickness he tells me that creatures with summoning sickness can still block creatures.

Comment: I also VTC'd this out of custom, but I don't think it's an actual dupe, since the question itself being referenced never mentions blocking, although the answer does.

Comment: You don't have to describe everything summoning sickness doesn't do for a reader to be able to derive that information from a description of what summoning sickness does.

Comment: @J.Sallé The duplicate target question does call out that the creature can still block as can be seen from this line in the answser. "Specifically, the creature cannot be declared as an attacker during your combat phase. It can still block, fight, or be put onto the battlefield attacking."

Comment: A comprehensive list of things that summoning sickness does affect also tells you every single thing it doesn't affect. It's not reasonable for an answer to list all the things it doesn't mean, as there are an unlimited number of those.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, you can block with a creature affected by summoning sickness.**

This is the Comprehensive Rule about "summoning sickness"; I emphasized the relevant parts in your case:

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. **A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began.** This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

As you can see, at no point the rule states that you cannot block with a creature affected by "summoning sickness".